# How to combine sha1( column + php string) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do the following but it isnt working, how can I make it work correct?

```
SELECT * FROM `exchange` WHERE SHA1(`email` + "'.$salt.'") = "'.$token.'"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `exchange` 
WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(`email`, 'yourSALT')) = 'yourTOKEN'
```